# Create div upon keyevent

Tags: javascript, var, keyevent

I would like for a div to be created upon key event, so if I press a specific key, such as K for example, a div will be created.

I have this code that creates a div on page load. However, I have issues with figuring out how to add a key event.

Could somebody help me?

The javascript:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');


div.innerHTML = "...";
div.style.color = 'red';
div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
div.style.width = '40px';
div.style.height = '40px';
div.style.float = 'left';


div.setAttribute('class', 'linda'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
document.body.appendChild(div);


var div = document.createElement('div');


div.innerHTML = "...";
div.style.color = 'blue';
div.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
div.style.width = '40px';
div.style.height = '40px';
div.style.float = 'left';


div.setAttribute('class', 'bella'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: you need to add an event listener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.  Here's an example of a keyup event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
function keyDownTextField(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 75) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = "...";
        div.style.color = 'blue';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        div.style.width = '40px';
        div.style.height = '40px';
        div.style.float = 'left';
        div.setAttribute('class', 'bella'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In key events, the keys are identified by a unique key code.
So if the code is 75, an alert is triggered. 
Here you can dynamically render elements to the DOM

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 75) {
        alert("K is pressed ");
    }
});
```